# Is field expansion syntax costly (in terms of rate limiting) compared to level queries?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I need to query targeting and insights information for all AdSets of a campaign.  I have figured out 2 ways of doing it:

1. Field-expansion: `{CAMPAIGN_ID}/AdSets?fields=insights{impressions},targeting`
2. Execute 2 queries (ordinary and leveled): `{CAMPAIGN_ID}/AdSets?fields=targeting`, `{CAMPAIGN_ID}/Insights?fields=impressions&level=ad`

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423184/possible-to-specify-date-preset-with-insights-edge-in-facebook-ads-api), where the answer states that the first expansion will efficiently execute multiple queries for each adset insight and will cost a lot compared to a level query. So my question: Is that really so and is it better to run 2 queries instead (which logically is more expensive)?

P.S. Is it possible to get the "cost" of the query in the result perhaps? Then I can just test. Created a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021865/is-it-possible-to-get-the-rate-limiting-cost-of-the-api-query) for this.

Comment: why not just test what takes longer?

Comment: It's not about what takes longer, it's about what's more expensive for rate-limiting. I don't think it has 1 to 1 mapping to time it takes to execute.

Answer (score 1):

It is 1 API call, as long as you don´t use batch requests. In that case, each call in the batch counts as one separate call.

Comment: So expansion does not add anything special towards rate limiting? Even though documentation says that it works like many subrequests (kind of)

Comment: exactly, not that i know of. but honestly, if you really hit api limits, you are doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: That's not quite true, since I am manipulating thousands of ads for multiple customers, so it's rather possible to hit the limit

Comment: you are using different tokens for those, it should be no big deal.