# Is it possible to set date_preset on fields using Facebook's GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the following query that I need to limit the dates on:

```
<Ad Campaign ID>/ads?fields=adset.fields(id),insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach,actions)
```

This is all well and good, and provides exactly the data needed in the format needed. But I need to limit the insights to the previous day, i.e., `date_preset = yesterday`.

To give a data sample of what this currently returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "adset": {
        "id": "<id>"
      },
      "insights": {
        "data": [
          {
            "impressions": "1483",
            "spend": "39.11",
            "reach": "837",
            "actions": [
              {
                "action_type": "post",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "post_reaction",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "comment",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "link_click",
                "value": "25"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "landing_page_view",
                "value": "22"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "post_engagement",
                "value": "29"
              },
              {
                "action_type": "page_engagement",
                "value": "29"
              }
            ],
            "date_start": "2021-09-20",
            "date_stop": "2021-10-19"
          }
        ],
      },
      "id": "<id>"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a few methods of doing this, though nothing has worked:

- Gets the data for the last month (ignores preset)

  - `<Ad Campaign ID>/ads?fields=adset.fields(id),insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach,actions)&date_preset=yesterday`
- Gets none of the `insights` fields, only the `adset` data

  - `<Ad Campaign ID>/ads?fields=adset.fields(id),insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach,actions).date_preset(yesterday)`
  - `<Ad Campaign ID>/ads?fields=adset.fields(id),insights.date_preset(yesterday){impressions,spend,reach,actions}`

Apologies if some of these queries seem like nonsense, first time using this and the Graph API hasn't quite "clicked" with me yet, so this might be me fundamentally misunderstanding what the syntax does in a couple places. Hopefully you get the goal.

I did see [references to querying on the Ad Account level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423184/possible-to-specify-date-preset-with-insights-edge-in-facebook-ads-api), and while this may work (it's a few years old, so might not for all I know) we cannot do this, as we need to query from a different account to the Ad Account. We don't have access to the Ad Account for queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the correct grammar is in fact one of the "non-working" examples I posted:

```
<Ad Campaign ID>/ads?fields=adset.fields(id),insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach,actions).date_preset(yesterday)
```

I had assumed that a lack of insight data would result in values of 0, not removal of the insight data altogether in the response. If I alter the date preset to a time frame that includes ad action data, I get the response that I'd expect. Therefore it's just a misunderstanding of what that endpoint returns in the event of no insight data for the time range.

This is completely missing from the API docs of course, which is a shame. Seems like you're just supposed to figure the API out by polling and noting behavior.